# converting hexa to decimal

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I would like to save some values that I'm reading from an image in a text file.

It was about square chars (uchar*). So I casted it into Float*.

It goes well. But the problem is that the values are in hexa!

How to convert the hexa into dec please? I have seen in Stack over flow (other answered questions that they are introducing some C# libraries but i,m using c++

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: it's just one instruction :
 FILE1 << (double*) img[i]<<;

Comment: and one of the numbers i'm having :
00000011 0000000B 0000000B 00000002

Comment: You should cast to double, not a double*

Answer (score 0):

is it because you casting it to a pointer and pointers are normaly dispalyed in hex. try casting as an double

Answer (score 0):

From the comment you posted I assume you want to write out the contents of the image, not the adresses of the pixels. In that case it is simply

```
FILE << img[i] << ...;
```

or, if you want to interpret the values as doubles

```
FILE << static_cast<double>(img[i]) << ...;
```

If you want to print out the the addresses of the pixels, but not the hex representation, you should use

```
FILE.setf(std::ios::dec);
FILE << &(img[i]) << ...
```